# In backpack hero what does the ghostly trait do?

Tags: backpack-hero

The spectral orb grants the `Ghostly` trait to adjacent items.

[image: spectral orb screenshot]

The ghostly trait says "This Item cannot be detected".

[image: ghostly description]

What does that mean?  What are the effects of ghostly?